# How To Disable Per Request (URL Based) Claims Authorization in WCF?

Tags: wcf, url, authorization, wif, claims

I have a WCF service which uses claims based authorization.

What I want to do is to attribute an operation with a `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` and only have the authorization check trigger once in my custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager`. However I am finding that this authorization check is being triggered twice; once for the URL and then a second time on the operation itself.

I can't find much information on this subject, but what I have found indicates that this is by design. Is it possible for me to overwrite this behavior and not perform any authorization on the URL, and only authorization based on the operation?

I have no interest in authorizing based on URLs, and would really rather avoid adding claims for each and every URL as I am likely to have a lot of them and they may change in future.

I have read several articles, and seen videos from Dominick Baier on this subject, and while I have learnt a lot from these I still can't find an answer to this. Is this simply not possible and I just have to deal with having to authorize based on the URL as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change this behavior - what I did is to write a custom claims permission attribute that does emit different claim types. This way I could distinguish between the per-request invocation and the explicit attribute.

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/tree/master/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/Authorization

or the Thinktecture.IdentityModel nuget package.

Comment: Ah I see, a reasonable work around I guess - thank you. I thought there was some extensibility point I was missing that would allow me to override the behaviour entirely.